# How to replace dom element by react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The output of my rich text editor is a plain `html`. I render it using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` on a `div` element. However, my plain html is quite limited in terms of interactivity. Let's say I have a node like

```
<a href="/users/userA"/ id="userA">
```

This is a simple link to user page. However I'd like add hover card functionality to it. I have my custom React component `UserLink` which implements this hover card using external libraries like `RadixUI`. Is it possible to somehow replace this simple `a` tag by my custom component after initial rendering? Or what is the other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library such as react-html-parser, which converts an HTML string into React components. It also allows replacing specified elements with React components.

Here's an example with react-html-parser:

```
import ReactHtmlParser, { convertNodeToElement } from 'react-html-parser';

function transform(node, index) {
  if (node.type === 'tag' && node.name === 'a') {
    return <UserLink key={index} href={node.attribs.href}>{node.children[0].data}</UserLink>;
  }
}

function MyComponent({ html }) {
  return <div>{ReactHtmlParser(html, { transform })}</div>;
}
```

In the transform function, an `<a>` tag with `href /users/userA` will be transformed to `<UserLink href="/users/userA">`.

This way, you can replace certain tags from your HTML string with your own custom React Component. The UserLink component can be defined as per your requirements, including hover functionality or any other custom behaviors.

Comment: Thank you! I used this package instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser#replace. It's hovewer a pity that I can't use `if (node instanceof HTMLAnhorElement)` - that would simplify things